# Iterating over JSON and making substitutions using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

EDIT: I have redone this question in its entirety as I discovered a flaw in my original: I CAN access ALL the data I need to get my output in a single call to the API.

My API call results in this JSON [abbreviated for clarity]:

```
{
    "lights": {
        "8": {
            "name": "Room 1 Main"
        }
    },
    "groups": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Room 1",
            "lights": [
                "8",
                "9",
                "10",
                "11",
                "12"
            ]
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "1": {
            "name": "Light  ON",
            "conditions": [{
                    "address": "/sensors/9/state/presence",
                    "operator": "eq",
                    "value": "true"
                },
                {
                    "address": "/sensors/10/state/lightlevel",
                    "operator": "lt",
                    "value": "12000"
                }
            ],
            "actions": [{
                "address": "/lights/8/state",
                "method": "PUT",
                "body": {
                    "on": true
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "sensors": {
        "9": {
            "name": "Room 1 Motion"
        },
        "10": {
            "name": "Room 1 Lux"
        }
    }
}
```

`rules` has references to `lights`, `sensors`, and (elsewhere) `groups`. I want to get output of each rule that substitutes the `name` of the object for the numeric reference. Using my example, output for Rule 1 would be something like:

```
{
    "name": "Light ON",
    "conditions": ["Room 1 Motion eq true",
        "Room 1 Lux lt 12000"
    ],
    "actions": "Room 1 Main on true"
}
```

So my question is: how can I iterate over each rule and then over each condition and action and use the values from sensors, lights, or groups to print that name instead of the reference?

FURTHER EDIT: Not all of the actions have `on` in the body. The variations are `flag` and `status`. For on and flag the permitted values are true|false and for status it's enabled|disabled.

Comment: Is making those associative arrays available to your jq program the crux of the problem you're having?  It would really help if you followed the [mcve] guidelines more closely.

Comment: Yes. If I could make the arrays available to jq I'd certainly be able to get further. That said, it is possible to get the same key|value data (as I have in the arrays) into jq as JSON. In that case, my problem would be how to combine three sets of JSON objects in order to process them in jq.  I'll have a think about recasting my question as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited answer:

`script.jq`:

```
def find($root):
  (.address | capture("^/(?<type>\\w+)/(?<name>\\w+)"; "g")) as $c
  | $root[$c.type][$c.name];

. as $root | .rules | [to_entries[].value | {
  name: .name, 
  conditions: [.conditions[] | "\(find($root).name) \(.operator) \(.value)"],
  actions: [.actions[] | find($root).name + (.body | to_entries[0] | " \(.key) \(.value)")]
}]
```

This probably can be done in a much more elegant way, but it works.

```json
$ jq -f script.jq test.json
[
  {
    "name": "Light  ON",
    "conditions": [
      "Room 1 Motion eq true",
      "Room 1 Lux lt 12000"
    ],
    "actions": [
      "Room 1 Main on true"
    ]
  }
]
```

Differences from example output:

1. `actions` is an array, because `actions` field in `rules` is an array.
2. An array wraps the resulting objects, so that the output is valid JSON when there're multiple rules, e.g:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Light ON",
    ...
  },
  {
    "name": "Light OFF",
    ...
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies for the delay, but you'll see from my edited question that I discovered - embarrassingly - that I do have access to more useful data.

Comment: Thank you again. There are a couple of things in there that I haven't tried before: using a function and a capture filter; so I've now taken time to read-up on them. Your solution gives me a solid foundation to pursue my ideas!

Comment: Actually, I have one more question please : Not all of the actions have `on` in the body. The variations are `flag` and `status`. For `on` and `flag` the permitted values are true|false and for `status` it's enabled|disabled. With your code, I obviously get a value of null when there is no `on`, but I am struggling to see how I can say something like: 'if on != null, then print body.on, elif flag != null then print body.flag etc (and the string literals for in/flag/status would also need to change).

Comment: Edited again :) You should probably add this info to the question, so that other people that stumble upon this know what's going on without reading the comments.

Comment: Thanks again. That does exactly what I want. Edited again as suggested ;)

Comment: I've found something that's not working as expected: for a rule that has these actions: `"actions": [
      {
        "address": "/rules/9",
        "method": "PUT",
        "body": {
          "status": "enabled"
        }
      },
      {
        "address": "/rules/11",
        "method": "PUT",
        "body": {
          "status": "enabled"
        }
      }
    ]` nothing is being returned (just an empty array []). Could you explain a bit please about how your script works so that I can try to troubleshoot this myself?

Comment: I removed a trailing `/` from the `capture` regex, should work now. The problem was that `find` function couldn't find anything if `address` field didn't have a slash after the number, like in `/rules/9`. Because of that the whole string building expression returned `empty` and nothing was getting added to the `actions` array. P.S. That slash wasn't required in the regex anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

This response deals with the problem of
"importing" the values of an associative bash array into JSON.
The approach here requires one invocation of jq per bash array.

For flexibility, we'll define a bash function that will take the bash array name as an argument, and produce the corresponding JSON object (i.e. dictionary):

```
function toJSON {
  local v="$1"
  jq -n '$ARGS.positional | [_nwise(length/2)] | transpose | map({(.[0]): .[1]}) | add' --args \
    $(eval "printf \"%s\\n\" \"\${!$v[@]}\"") $(eval "printf \"%s\\n\" \"\${$v[@]}\"")
}
```

You could then use this like so:

```
jq --argjson sensors $(toJSON sensors) --argjson lights $(toJSON lights) ....
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Apologies for the delay, but you'll see from my edited question that I discovered - embarrassingly - that I do have access to more useful data.